# Byobu: Keybindings only respond in first tab; not responsive in new tabs or windows

Tags: shortcut-keys, byobu, xfce4-terminal

I start Byobu and the first tab responds perfectly to all my keybindings. I can turn keybindings on and off and baby doves hatch from terminal outputs.

```
~ $ > byobu-keybindings
Byobu keybindings: [OFF]
---------------------------------------- | Mon Jan 14 20:08:53 | azatar@orion
~ $ > byobu-keybindings
Byobu keybindings: [ON]
```

Then, I open an second tab and my world begins to crumble. None of the keybindings are responsive.

```
~ $ > byobu-keybindings 
---------------------------------------- | Mon Jan 14 20:09:13 | azatar@orion

~ $ >
```

Attempting to enable/disable keybindings shows no output and the session title is like that of a standard terminal emulator: no indication that it's using byobu anything.

[image: Good Byobu - Keybindings WORK!!] [image: Bad Byobu - Keybindingd NOT WORKING!!?]

```
    ^--- Good Byobu Tab (1st)           Bad Byobu Tab (2nd, 3rd, etc)---^
```

What exactly could the problem be here? Is the session not loading properly on the second, nth tabs? I checked preferences, but I can't seem to find anything obvious or it's just late... and I'm tired. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone...because it helped me... and I seem to have missed the fact that this behavior may be disabled by default.

From the [Byobu Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu):

> **Enable/Disabl**e Byobu can be configured to run by default at every text login (SSH or TTY). That behavior can be toggled with the
>   byobu-enable and byobu-disable commands.
>
> ```
> byobu-enable
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> byobu-disable
> ```

SO, I just needed to run `byobu-enable` to let my xfce terminal know that I want byobu in all tabs and windows opened. ...and the inner-child rejoices.